# how to plot predicted lines over observed values and check residual plots for the selected models from a list

Tags: r, regression

Example data:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x + c(-0.5,0.5)
a <- rnorm(10)
b <- rnorm(10)
c <- rnorm(10)
data <- data.frame(x,y,a, b,c)
```

Here I wrote a function to calc different models at the same time on a single ind variable (z) as bellow.

```
func <-function(z){
  fit1 <- lm( y~ x + z )
  fit2 <- lm( y~x + I(z^2))
  fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) + z)
  library(splines)
  fit4 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) + z)
  fit5 <- lm( y~ns(x, 9) + z)
  return(list(fit1, fit2, fit3, fit4, fit5))
}

mod1 <- func(data$a) 
mod2 <- func(data$b)
```

mod1 and mod2 contain a list of 5 models each. Now first I want to select 2nd and 4th models of mod1 and 3rd, 4th, 5th models of mod2 and then plot these selected predicted models over observed value of a and b respectively. Second want to check residual plot of them.

```
sel1 <- mod1[c(2,4)]
sel2 <- mod2[c(3,4,5)]
```

I am trying to use predict function but gives me an error "no applicable method for 'predict' applied to an object of class "list". 
I my question is how to plot predicted lines over observed values and check residual plots for the selected models from a list.

```
pred <- predict(sel1)
plot(resid(sel1))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use `lapply` or a `for` loop to run through the list.

Comment: `lapply(sel1, predict)` and `lapply(sel1, resid)` give no errors. Also, don't put `library(splines)` in the function, call it just once outside it.

Comment: Thank you for your responce! It works but I want to plot predicted values of the selected models together with observed value in a single plot. Is it possible to do it through the list?